# c# keeping custom attributes in separate assembly

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

I have custom attributes and classes which are using those attributes. These attributes are used for Property Grid when class object is selected. Currently both classes and attributes are in the same assembly. Within attributes I have some Form objects. Because of these Form objects I want to keep attributes in a separate assembly. However than it results in a circular reference.  Could you please help me on this issue?

Sample:

I have business object whose property can be displayed in PropertyGridControl:

```
    public class Field
    {
        public Field()
        {

        }

        private int _Type;

        [CustomPropertyEditorMarker(typeof(RepositoryItemForFieldDataType))]
        public int Type
        {
            get { return _Type; }
            set
            {
                _Type = value;
            }
        }
    }

    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
    public sealed class CustomPropertyEditorMarker : Attribute
    {
        public CustomPropertyEditorMarker(Type editorType)
        {
            EditorType = editorType;
        }

        public readonly Type EditorType;
    }

    public sealed class RepositoryItemForFieldDataType : RepositoryItemLookUpEdit
    {
        public RepositoryItemForFieldDataType()
        {
                // Populating LookupEdit details here
        }

        private void On_ButtonClick()
        {
            // Here initializing existing Form class and show it
        }
    }

When Field object is selected, PropertGridControl analyze selected object and checking which property has above Attribute. If yes, then initialize it.

        private void SelectObject(object obj)
        {
            this.Rows.Clear();
            this.DefaultEditors.Clear();
            this.RepositoryItems.Clear();

            if ((this.LastSelectedObject as ApplicationDomainItemBase) != null)
            {
                (this.LastSelectedObject as ApplicationDomainItemBase).IsSelected = false;
            };

            this.SelectedObject = null;

            this.SelectedObject = obj;

            if (!(this.SelectedObject is ConfigurationObjectManagerBase))
            {
                foreach (var propInfo in this.SelectedObject.GetType().GetProperties())
                {
                    object[] objFieldAtts = propInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CustomPropertyEditorMarker), true);

                    if (objFieldAtts != null && objFieldAtts.Length > 0)
                    {
                        if (this.GetRowByFieldName(propInfo.Name) != null)
                        {
                            RepositoryItem repItem = Activator.CreateInstance(((CustomPropertyEditorMarker)objFieldAtts[0]).EditorType) as RepositoryItem;
                            this.GetRowByFieldName(propInfo.Name).Properties.RowEdit = repItem;
                        };
                    };
                };
            };

            this.LastSelectedObject = obj;
        }
```

Currently both of business object classes and Attributes are within same assembly and need to separate them. However I can't, because business object property is decorated with attribute name and will need to add reference. It will not be possible to add reference because Attribute classes has reference to business object classes. Hope it clear. Thanks.

Comment: Why the project where you are moving the attributes references the project that uses these attributes ? Can you provide more details on your dependencies ?

Comment: @user3185569, pls see edits. Thanks.

Comment: I only see one attribute class in your sample code, and it is not referencing any of the other classes. What am I missing. I don't see what's stopping you from moving that attribute class to a separate assembly and then referencing that assembly from the project that contains your domain objects.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the business object reference that is causing your problem, a general answer is as follows:

Base your business objects on interfaces which would be declared in either the same assembly as where you want to move your attributes, or another "base" assembly. Then refer to the business objects in your attributes via their interfaces.